# Обмен максимального элемента с главной диагональю

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
const int row = 3;
const int column = 3;
int arr[row][column];
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
        arr[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{

    int max = arr[i][i];

    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        if(arr[i][j] > max){
            max = arr[i][j];
        }
        swap(max, arr[i][i]);

}
cout << "\n\n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << endl;

}
return 0;
```

}

Как переделать цикл так, чтобы он выполнял задачу
`Найти в каждой строке наибольший элемент и поменять местами с элементом главной диагонали`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже пользуетесь такой стандартной функцией, как `std::swap`. То почему бы вам не воспользоваться стандартными алгоритмами?

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const size_t ROW = 3;
    const size_t COLUMN = 3;

    int arr[ROW][COLUMN];

    std::srand((unsigned int)std::time(nullptr));

    for (auto &row : arr)
    {
        std::generate(std::begin(row), std::end(row),
            [] { return std::rand() % 100 - 50; });
    }

    for (const auto &row : arr)
    {
        for (auto x : row) std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::right << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        int *max = std::max_element(std::begin(arr[i]), std::end(arr[i]));
        std::iter_swap(max, arr[i] + i);
    }

    for (const auto &row : arr)
    {
        for (auto x : row) std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::right << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль, к примеру, может быть таким

```
 27   8  41
 41 -41  -4
 -7 -28 -35

 41   8  27
-41  41  -4
-35 -28  -7
```

Если вы хотите найти максимальный элемент в каждой строке матрицы самостоятельно, то можете воспользоваться следующими циклами

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
{
    size_t max = 0;
    for (size_t j = 1; j < COLUMN; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i][max] < arr[i][j]) max = j;
    }
    std::swap(arr[i][max], arr[i][i]);
}
```

Что касается ваших циклов по поиску максимального элемента и обмена с элементом диагонали

```
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{

    int max = arr[i][i];

    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        if(arr[i][j] > max){
            max = arr[i][j];
        }
        swap(max, arr[i][i]);

}
```

то, во-первых, вы перепутали колонки со строками, хотя для квадратной матрицы это и не важно, но тем не менее, и обмениваете значение локальной переменной `max`, объявленной как

```
    int max = arr[i][i];
```

с диагональным элементом